# Dynamically set Input value from API Data Angular 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular8

This is my code where I want to set input value dynamically coming from my api data later when I click send it will be saved in Database. But I am not able to put data inside input Dynamically please help me what is the approach to do it.

```
<button (click)="getnewsstack()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Get News Stack</button>
<form [formGroup]="form" class="form-inline" *ngFor="let news of newsstack" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form)">
  <div class="card-header text-center h3">
    News Stack
     </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control rt no-radius"  value="{{news.title}}" formControlName="title"  [(ngModel)]="title">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input type="text" name="description" value="{{news.title}}" formControlName="description">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input type="text" name= " url" formControlName="url" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" name= " urlToImage" formControlName="urlToImage" >
</div>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Here is my Component file

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from 'src/app/services/news.service';
import {CAservice} from 'src/app/services/caservice.service'
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { get } from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-searchnews',
  templateUrl: './searchnews.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchnews.component.css']
})
export class SearchnewsComponent implements OnInit {

  newsstack=[];
  enableEdit = false;
  form: FormGroup;
  enableEditIndex = null;
  submitted: boolean= false;
  cadata = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    url: '',
    urlToImage:''

  };


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private newsSearch:NewsService,private CAservice:CAservice) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getnewsstack() {
    this.newsSearch.getAll().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.newsstack = data;
        this.createForm();
        this.form.controls.title.setValue(data.title);
        this.form.controls.description.setValue(data.description);
        this.form.controls.url.setValue(data.url);
        console.log(this.newsstack);

      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });;
  }

  createForm(){
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl(''),
      description: new FormControl(''),
      url: new FormControl(''),
      urlToImage: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  submitForm(form: FormGroup) {
    console.log('Title', form.value.title);
    console.log('description', form.value.description);
    console.log('url', form.value.url);
    console.log('urlToImage', form.value.urlToImage);
  }


  saveNews(){
    var formData: any = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", this.form.get('title').value);
    formData.append("description", this.form.get('description').value);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form.getRawValue()));
  }

}
```

Data coming from Service file and able to get that in console.
[image]

Comment: I am quite sure that the problem is, that you initialize the FormControls with blank values (`title: new FormControl('')`). You would then need to have an input/change or some  other event change the data or set it via `.setValue()`.  I would create a new Component for the newsstack form with an `@Input()` value for the newsstack object and then just put the form and the init method in that new component, and initalize the formGroup with the newsStack object's data.

Comment: I modified this function but not working is anything there i am missing.   getnewsstack() {
    this.newsSearch.getAll().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.newsstack = data;
        this.createForm();
        this.form.controls.title.setValue(data.title);
        this.form.controls.description.setValue(data.description);
        this.form.controls.url.setValue(data.url);
        console.log(this.newsstack);

      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified my code below and I am getting data in my input field. Here I am sharing my code if it helps anyone later

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.newsSearch.getAll().subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.apiData = data.map((item: any) => {
      return {
        form: this.fb.group({
          selected: false
        }),
        ...item
      }
    });
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array(this.apiData.map(item => item.form))
    });
  });
}
```

this is my html

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of apiData; let i = index">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.selected">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img [src]="item.urlToImage" alt="{{item.title}}" width="100" height="75">
        </td>
        <td>
          <div *ngIf="!item.isEditing">{{ item.title }}</div>
          <div *ngIf="item.isEditing"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.title"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div *ngIf="!item.isEditing">{{ item.description }}</div>
          <div *ngIf="item.isEditing"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.description"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div *ngIf="!item.isEditing">
            <button (click)="editData(item, i)">Edit</button>
            <button (click)="saveData(item)">Save</button>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="item.isEditing">
            <button (click)="cancelEdit(item)">Cancel</button>
            <button (click)="saveData(item)">Save</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```